# How to call a javascript function from UIwebview when entering foreground?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I want to autorefresh UIwebview when the user enters into foreground.
This is my javascript function i want to run in my html file:

```
<script>
    function testfunctionforios() {
       refreshfunction();
    }
</script>
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connectToFcm];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;


    NSLog(@"in applicationdidbecomeactive");
    [self.viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testfunctionforios()"];
}
```

When i use applicationDidBecomeActive the javascript function is NOT called successfully but I see the NSLog message!

When I try to use webViewDidFinishLoad in
ViewController.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if ( webView == self.viewWeb )
    {
        NSLog(@"calling testfunction");
        [self.viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testfunctionforios()"];    
    }

}
```

the function is called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you load html in your code.

Comment: log viewWeb in AppDelegate. is it nil?

Comment: I load my html in the ViewController...I think Appdelegate has no access to the loaded html. How can i do this ?